# debugging stalled write() to std::cout from libc.so.6

Tags: python, c++, linux

I have just observed an extremely rare occurrence of stall in a binary.

Attaching gdb and switching to the relevant thread gives

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000330a4db79d in write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000330a471dd3 in _IO_new_file_write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000330a473385 in _IO_new_do_write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x000000330a4726df in _IO_new_file_overflow () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x000000330a46f437 in putc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f92d94864ea in sputc (__c=10 '\n', this=<optimized out>) at [..omitted..]/gcc-4.9.0-objdir/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:434
#6  std::ostream::put (this=0x3171f40 <std::cout>, __c=<optimized out>) at [..omitted..]/gcc-4.9.0-objdir/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:163
```

and strace gives

```
Process 14702 attached - interrupt to quit
write(1, "[...some string...]", 31
```

It has been there forever, writing to std::cout. What other information should I gather? How should one get to the bottom of this?

EDIT:
The binary is invoked by a python system, very deep inside, it's doing

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(
  command,
  shell=True,
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)
output = pipe.stdout.read()
pipe.wait()
```

Comment: This is quite common if `cout` is redirected to a pipe and the destination program does paging or waits for input from some other source before reading from the pipe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The binary is indeed invoked by python's subprocess. Is there anything one can do on the C++ side, or should one be working on the python side?

Comment: It depends what the right behavior is. What should the C++ process do if it's output isn't being read? Should it wait? Should it go on without waiting? Should the Python subprocess be reading all the output from the C++ process as quickly as possible? Figure out what should be happening and make it happen.

Comment: Thanks. Upon further reading, the python side ended up being the bad guy. I guess the C++ side can be made safer by spinning off a helper thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cout` is redirected to a pipe, then output will block if the process on the other end of the pipe doesn't read fast enough. You need to decide whether the C++ process should be constructed to continue to make forward progress even if writes to `cout` block or whether the other end of the pipe must read from the pipe. Figure out what's broken and fix it.